# React Navigation ERROR Unable to resolve originModulePath

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am new to coding and react native. I have been trying to set up an app with just some basic pages to practice with react navigation but keep getting thrown an error.

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve "./src/navigation/MainTabs" from "src/navigation/AppNavigator.js"
```

I am using expo and have installed these npm:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

Here is my code so far:

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator.js';

const App = () => {
 return (
  <NavigationContainer>
   <AppNavigator />
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
}

export default App;
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import MainTabs from './src/navigation/MainTabs';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
 return (
   <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name='MainTabs' component={MainTabs} />
   </Stack.Navigator>
 );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

**MainTabs.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import PartyMenuScreen from './src/screens/PartyMenuScreen';
import TableMenuScreen from './src/screens/TableMenuScreen';
import VacationMenuScreen from './src/screens/VacationMenuScreen';


const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MainTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
     <Tab.Screen name='Party Games' component={PartyMenuScreen} />
     <Tab.Screen name='Table Games' component={TableMenuScreen} />
     <Tab.Screen name='Vacation Games' component={VacationMenuScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MainTabs;
```

I have tried reinstalling the npm modules and renaming file paths. Beyond that I am not sure what to do. I believe it may have something to do with my dependencies but I am not sure how to troubleshoot them.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in `AppNavigator.js` import path for

```
import MainTabs from './src/navigation/MainTabs';
```

From the error message, I am assuming you have `AppNavigator.js` and `MainTabs.js` at the same level in folder hierarchy.
Replace above import with below:

```
import MainTabs from './MainTabs';
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. Used ../ for the imports because of the folder they were located in and changed the Tabs to Tab.